# Facing issue in flutter- RevenueCat in debug or run mode

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

Please refer this link
[https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter/issues/790](https://stackoverflow.com)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingListener found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingService found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.a found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.a.a found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.a.b found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.a.c found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.a.c$1 found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.a.d found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.a found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.c found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.d found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.e found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.c found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.c.a found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.c.b found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.c.c found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.c.d found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.c.e found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.d found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.e found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.ProductBuilder found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.ProductDataResponseBuilder found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.PurchaseResponseBuilder found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.PurchaseUpdatesResponseBuilder found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.ReceiptBuilder found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.UserDataBuilder found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.UserDataResponseBuilder found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.model.a found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.util.MetricsHelper found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.util.a found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.util.b found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.util.c found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.util.d found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.CoinsReward found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.FulfillmentResult found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.Product found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.Product$1 found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.ProductDataResponse found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.ProductDataResponse$RequestStatus found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.ProductType found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.PurchaseResponse found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.PurchaseResponse$RequestStatus found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.PurchaseUpdatesResponse found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.PurchaseUpdatesResponse$RequestStatus found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.Receipt found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.RequestId found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.RequestId$1 found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.UserData found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.UserData$1 found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.UserDataResponse found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)
Duplicate class com.amazon.device.iap.model.UserDataResponse$RequestStatus found in modules jetified-amazon-appstore-sdk-3.0.3 (com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.3) and jetified-in-app-purchasing-2.0.76 (in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar)

flutter clean ,
update dependecy